# Reverse string using recursion with new character between each letter in string

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to create a script to reverse the order of a string and put a new character between each letter of the string. For example, let's say I have the word Difficulty, I would like it to be reversed, and a new character, such as a hyphen, added between each character.

> Input: "Difficulty"
>
> Output: "y-t-l-u-c-i-f-f-i-D"

The code I am I came up with adds an extra asterisk at the start of the script:

```py
def try_reverse(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    else:
        return try_reverse(s[1:]) +"-" + s[0]
```

> Output: "-y-t-l-u-c-i-f-f-i-D"

The only catch is that it needs to be done as a recursion.

Comment: Change `if s == "": return s` to `if len(s) <= 1: return s`

Comment: That's brilliant. Didn't even think of that. Add it as the solution, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to end the recursion where there is one letter left:

```
def try_reverse(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    else:
        return try_reverse(s[1:]) +"-" + s[0]
```